# Empty Child and another child attribute vlaues

Tags: c#, xml

Hi All: Could you please tell me what is the mistake in gettting the child & child2 attribute values?

I'm getting the valu of the node attribute but not for the childs nodes.

Overall i need to get Name value from products, Visibile value  from the element Visibilities, and Price value from elment Prices.

**Code:**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("Prices.txt");
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("RetroPrintProduct");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name={0} ", node.Attributes["Name"].Value);
            foreach (XmlNode child in node.SelectNodes("ProductVisibility "))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Visible={0}", child.Attributes["Visible"].Value);
                foreach (XmlNode child2 in child.SelectNodes("Prices"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Price={0}", child2.Attributes["Price"].Value);
                }
            }

        }
```

**XML file:**

```
<Item>
    <RetroPrintProduct Nino123="d89e280b-c8d5-4da2-87da-36e4a57e2867" Nino1="2022ProfileProducts.RetroPrintProduct" Sys_Index="UpdateOnly" DefaultIconName="RetroPrints_10x8x2_R_Metallic.png" DefaultOutputProfileName="Nino" DefaultOutputProfileTypeFullName="2022Profile" Name="Item Retro">
      <ShippingMethodPrices Index="Replace" />
      <Visibilities Index="Replace" />
    </RetroPrintProduct>
  
    <RetroPrintProduct Nino123="67d1577d-7baf-4b3f-a9fb-9d52404e45f4" Nino1="2022ProfileProducts.RetroPrintProduct" Sys_Index="UpdateOnly" DefaultIconName="RetroPrints_10x8x2_S_Normal.png" DefaultOutputProfileName="Nino" DefaultOutputProfileTypeFullName="2022Profile" Name="Item 2 Retro">
      <ShippingMethodPrices Index="Replace" />
      <Visibilities Index="Replace">
        <ProductVisibility Nino123="cc0096e0-d964-4e45-93f7-9258ddee148d" Sys_GlobalUniqueId="cc0096e0-d964-4e45-93f7-9258ddee148d" Sys_ReplicationId="39f43856-a16f-4555-b519-ccf71b97ee58" Nino1="2022.ProductVisibility" Activated="True" Noprices="False" PhotoSource="EndUserPhotos" BackgroundColor="Default" Icon="" Image="" IsUnusableByLicense="False" MaxDate="2999-12-31" MinDate="1900-01-01" Name="" Object="Visible" Visible="True" ProductLibrary="" ReplicationId="39f43856-a16f-4555-b519-ccf71b97ee58" SysCode="">
          <Prices Index="Replace">
            <ProductPrice Nino123="4ca2658e-3e07-4636-b33f-d87fb021288a" Sys_GlobalUniqueId="4ca2658e-3e07-4636-b33f-d87fb021288a" Sys_ReplicationId="3e75b8f4-d1b6-41fe-be9e-d2858caf6eb9" Nino1="2022.ProductPrice" FixFee="0" ServiceFee="0" Mode="Replace" FromQuantity="1" Price="0.5" ProductPriceType="PerPageQuantity" ProductLibrary="" ReplicationId="3e75b8f4-d1b6-41fe-be9e-d2858caf6eb9" SysCode="" />
          </Prices>
        </ProductVisibility>
      </Visibilities>
    </RetroPrintProduct>
    </Item>
```

Comment: Have you checked that you are using the correct element and attribute names?  I don't see any nodes named `<Visibility>`  I see `<Visibilities>` and `<ProductVisibility>`, is one of those what you want to select?  And I don't see any attributes named `Visible` either, I see `OrderableObjectVisibility`.

Comment: @db: under Visibilities we have the attribute Visible="True" also under ProductVisibility /prices, we have price attribute. To me i think i'm looking at the correct attribute names. thanks

Comment: OK, I found `Visible="True"`.  For some reason my browser wasn't finding it when it has scrolled offscreen.  But what about the element names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some nesting when searching through the nodes. `ProductVisibility` is under `Visibilites`, not `RetroPrintProduct`, and `Price` is an attribute of `ProductPrice`, not `Prices`.

Something like this should do the trick (note that I named the nodes in code to match the xml names to make it easier to remember which child is which):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\temp\Prices.xml");
XmlNodeList retroPrintProducts = doc.GetElementsByTagName("RetroPrintProduct");

foreach (XmlNode retroPrintProduct in retroPrintProducts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name={0} ", retroPrintProduct.Attributes["Name"].Value);

    foreach (XmlNode visibility in retroPrintProduct.SelectNodes("Visibilities"))
    {
        foreach (XmlNode productVisibilty in visibility.SelectNodes("ProductVisibility"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Visible={0}", productVisibilty.Attributes["Visible"].Value);

            foreach (XmlNode price in productVisibilty.SelectNodes("Prices"))
            {
                foreach (XmlNode productPrice in price.SelectNodes("ProductPrice"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Price={0}", productPrice.Attributes["Price"].Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```